# "Один умница мальчишка знакомый – сын моих друзей", - необходимо ли перестраивать?

Tags: пунктуация, порядок-слов, однородные-неоднородные-определения

> У меня есть один умница мальчишка знакомый – сын моих друзей. Ему
>   восемь лет. Человек крайне чувствительный. И болезненно гордый.
>   Талантлив, пишет  романы. Много размышляет. С ним очень интересно
>   говорить.

Надо ли изображать:

*У меня есть один умница мальчишка – знакомый, сын моих друзей.*

*У меня есть один знакомый – умница мальчишка, сын моих друзей.*

Или как-то ещё? А как есть - можно?

Comment: На мой взгляд, "один умница мальчишка знакомый" — слишком много подряд существительных.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше так:

***Есть у меня  один знакомый умница мальчишка – сын моих друзей.***

*Умница мальчишка* — это *умный мальчишка*, нет дефиса по правилам Розенталя.

Получается: *знакомый умный мальчишка* — вполне корректное сочетание.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы всё-таки перестроила, чтобы конструкция была более читабельна. Можно использовать вариант Sharon(определение **знакомый**  лучше смотрится перед определяемым словом, чем после него), можно Ваши.

Можно и так:

*У меня есть один знакомый мальчишка, сын моих друзей, - просто умница.*